# How do I make application context available to all classes in application in the app?

Tags: android, resources, android-context

How do I make application context available to all classes in application in the app?
My supporting classes need to be able to access it in order to access resourses.

Answer (score 1):

Best answer: pass in a `Context` to your supporting classes' methods, as the application context may or may not work for your particular cases. You will notice, for example, that many supporting classes in Android take this approach, and it is generally a good idea to follow the patterns set forth by the platform developers.

Possibly tolerable answer: use a static data member to hold a reference to the `Application` object. Be very very careful that you do not introduce memory leaks in the process.